# How to modify price and currency in order receipt email with woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, email-notifications

i'm doing a woocommerce plugin in order to allow payments with paypal using foreign currency. It work but the problem is that the order email is still containing default prices and default currency.

What I have tried to do is to change them using this action hook:

```
do_action ('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email);
```

… inside email template file `email-order-details.php`, but I don't now how I should modify an order object to change the prices of each item, I didn't see a method like set_price or set_total inside the woocommerce doc for order class.

How this could be done? Any advice please?